# Speed Up Pandas Remove "nan" and Spaces, Memory Issues

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with fairly large dataframes, and final step in to remove np.nan, uppercase strings, remove spaces, commas, replace NaN, NaT with "".   I have code that works, but if large datasets causes memory crash.  Any ideas how to optimize this code?  I've tried various techniques.

Below is a sample small dataframe to show where i'm at:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(-1, 'bronze', -1.0),
               ('silv er', '-1.0', 'br,on ze'),
               ('NaN', 'silver', 'nan'),
               ('', 'NaT', 'NONE')],
                columns=('Canada', 'China', 'South Korea'))


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

def remove_nan_negatives(df):
   t1 = time.time()
   df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace = True)
   # select numeric columns
   numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns
   df[numeric_columns] = df[numeric_columns].fillna("")

    non_numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns
    df[non_numeric_columns] = df[non_numeric_columns].fillna("")
    df[non_numeric_columns] = df[non_numeric_columns].replace("nan", "")
    df[non_numeric_columns] = df[non_numeric_columns].replace("NAN", "")
    df[non_numeric_columns] = df[non_numeric_columns].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())

    df[non_numeric_columns] = df[non_numeric_columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

    df = df.replace("-1", "") 
    df = df.replace("-1.0", "") 
    df = df.replace(-1, "") 
    df = df.replace(-1.0, "") 
    df = df.replace("NaN", "")
    df = df.replace("NAN", "")
    df = df.replace("NaT", "")
    df = df.replace("NAT", "")
    df = df.replace("NONE", "")
    df = df.replace(",", "")
    df = df.fillna(value="")
    t2 = time.time()
    print('time taken', str((t2-t1)))
    return df

remove_nan_negatives(df)
# time taken 0.04082131385803223
```

Comment: Why is cleaning up the dataset the final step? If your data comes from plain text/CSV files you can clean it up before using text processing, and then load it as a data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following function, which remove some duplicate work in yours:

```
def remove_nan_negatives_fast(df):
    non_numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns
    df[non_numeric_columns] = df[non_numeric_columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.upper().str.strip())

    replacements = {np.inf: "",
                    -np.inf: "",
                    "-1": "",
                    "-1.0": "",
                    -1: "",
                    -1.0: "",
                    "NaN": "",
                    "NaT": "",
                    "nan": "",
                    "NAN": "",
                    "NAT": "",
                    "NONE": "",
                    ",": "", }

    df = df.replace(replacements).fillna("")
    return df
```

On my machine it gives the following results:

```
%timeit remove_nan_negatives(df)
19.8 ms ± 3.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit remove_nan_negatives_fast(df1)
5.02 ms ± 386 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So about a 5x speed-up gain. Notice that the main gain comes from using a dictionary in the [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function, at the same time saving the creation of intermediate DataFrames.

Comment: messejo - this helps, but i still need to uppercase, strip white spaces, and remove commas.  so i add that in and back close to where i started (net 10% improvement)

     df[non_numeric_columns] = df[non_numeric_columns].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())
     df[non_numeric_columns] = df[non_numeric_columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
     df.replace(',','', regex=True, inplace=True)

Comment: @jKraut This line: `df[non_numeric_columns] = df[non_numeric_columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.upper().str.strip())` uppers and strip whitespaces

Comment: @jKraut And also this thing `df.replace(',','', regex=True, inplace=True)` was not on your original code, and the ',' is one of the keys of the dictionary so, not sure what do you mean

Comment: Mesego - the ',' for some reason didn't replace it if inside of a string, so i added that other  ````df.replace(',','', regex=True, inplace=True)```` and it caught it.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it if you don't want to have to explicitly specify everything to remove:

```
import time
import math

def remove_negative(x):
    if (not isinstance(x,int)) and (not isinstance(x,float)):
        return x
    if x<0.0:
        return ""
    else:
        return x
    
def remove_uppercase(x):
    if not isinstance(x,str):
        return x
    if x.isupper():
        return ""
    else:
        return x

def remove_specific(x):
    to_remove = [' ',',','NaN','NaT']
    if x in to_remove:
        return ""
    else:
        return x
    
def remove_nan(x):
    if isinstance(x,str):
        return x
        
    if math.isnan(x):
        return ""
    else:
        return x
    
def remove_stringnums(x):
    try:
        float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
    else:
        return ""

def remove_nan_negatives(df):
    
    cols = []

    for col in df.columns:
        cols.append(df[col].apply(remove_negative)
                           .apply(remove_uppercase)
                           .apply(remove_specific)
                           .apply(remove_stringnums)
                           .apply(remove_nan))


    return pd.concat(cols,axis=1)



t1 = time.time()
remove_nan_negatives(df)
t2 = time.time()
print('time taken', str((t2-t1)))


#      Canada   China   South Korea
# 0             bronze  
# 1    silv er            br,on ze
# 2             silver  
# 3         

# time taken 0.0038068294525146484
```

Comment: This implementation: `2.58 ms ± 251 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Original implementation: `20.4 ms ± 972 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`